# Change the url "localhost/rootdirectory/folder1/two.html" to "localhost/rootdirectory-folder1-two" in address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-shortener

I'm very new to this forums & also to PHP Developing.
I want to learn `.htaccess` concept fully, I know `.htaccess` is used to configure apache.
I tried alot of sites but couldn't understand clearly.

I have a query as, `project` is my root directory which contains `index.html` file and a folder which contains subfolder like this:

```
project
   |__index.html
   |__one
       |__two
           |__two.html
```

`index.html` contains an anchor link which directs to `two.html`, then I can see the url link as `localhost/project/one/two/two.php` in address bar

I want to change the url

`localhost/project/one/two/two.php`

to

```
localhost/project-one-two-two
```

It'd be very helpful if I get the exact result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest static mapping , easy to understand .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule project-one-two-two /project/one/two/two.php [L]
```

For more dynamic rule , which will work for any  "dir-dir-dir-file" type of url :

```
RewriteRule ([a-z]*)-([a-z]*)-([a-z]*)-([a-z]*) /$1/$2/$3/$4.php [L]
```

You can use [Htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) for testing the results of RewriteRules

Comment: Thanks for the Reply & Advice "Rahul".
I'm testing from localhost using xampp. The actual folder hierarchy is as follows: "localhost/htaccess/one/two/inner.php" i.e; in "xampp/htdocs/htaccess/one/two/inner.php"..... if i type "localhost/htaccess/one/two/inner.php" the url in addressbar is not changing to "localhost/htaccess-one-two-inner" even after i modified .htaccess file as u said.

Comment: You are getting things wrong... Actual task of htaccess is to map from  permalink like htaccess-one-two-inner to actual file path like htaccess/one/two/inner.php .. so in browser we actually type : htaccess-one-two-inner and expect it to open htaccess/one/two/inner.php .

Comment: in .htaccess file i wrote:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?action=login [NC, L]

in index.php file:
<?php
if(isset($_GET["action"])){
    $action = $_GET["action"];
    echo "Action is : ".$action;
}else
    echo "Action is : None";

?>

but if i run this i'm getting server error error 500. Even if i deployed this files in free webhost ie.; www.000webhost.com it's also giving the same output. Is there anything wrong in this code or is there any problem with xampp ?

Comment: Remove the space before L .. replace [NC, L] with [NC,L]

Comment: Thanks! its working fine now, the problem is in xammp its need to restart but i'm using netbook and didn't restart from a month. After restart its all working smoothly.